# How to check if the TextField contains only (DOT) character

Tags: java

How to check if the TextField contains only (DOT) character. The TextField can contain the following below things...

```
.9 = > Valid
9. = > Valid
9.23 = >Valid
```

But if the TextField contains only (.), then the user should be thrown an error message. I cannot do a `Text.startsWith()` or neither `Text.contains()` as both may fail in other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regular expression

```
text.matches("\\d+|\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*")
```

- `\\d+` matches only digits
- `\\d*\\.\\d+` matches strings that start either with dot or digit and contain a dot
- `\\d+\\.\\d*` matches strings that start with digit, contain a dot and any number of digits
  after it

Keep in mind that numbers starting with 0 will also be accepted by this expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
text.equals(".")
```

or, to take whitespaces into account,

```
text.trim().equals(".")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also have to check that in addition to the dot you also have a digit, you should probably write a couple of regexps.

In your case a string is valid if it matches the following patterns:

```
\d+       // Digits without the dot
\d*\.\d+  // Number with some digits after the dot
\d+\.\d*  // Number with some digits before the dot
```

Comment: This is not correct. The capital D (\D) matches non-digits. It is the negated form of \d.

Answer (score -1):

you can just use two method

```
if(yourTextFieldName.getText().endsWith(".") && yourTExtFieldName.startsWith(".")) {
    //write your code here
}
```

Comment: This matches something like ".abc123."